# How do you inject a specific subclass based on the which class is instantiated with Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have these Repositories dependent on DataSources.

```
class LocationRepository: Repository<String>(LocationDataSource())
class ItemRepository: Repository<String>(ItemDataSource())
```

I would like to inject the Repository class with Hilt like this to prevent code duplication.

```
abstract class Repository<T> {

    @Inject lateinit var dataSource: DataSource<T>
    ...
}
```

I have tried this, but am not sure how to get Hilt to use the right ones.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class ItemDataSourceAnnotation

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class LocationDataSourceAnnotation

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataSourceModule {

    @ItemDataSourceAnnotation
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideItemDataSource(): DataSource{
        return ItemDataSource()
    }

    @LocationDataSourceAnnotation
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLocationDataSource(): DataSource{
        return LocationDataSource()
    }
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesItemRepository(
        @ItemDataSourceAnnotation itemDataSource: ItemDataSource
    ): ItemRepository {
        return ItemRepository()
    }
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesLocationRepository(
        @LocationDataSourceAnnotation locationDataSource: LocationDataSource
    ): LocationRepository {
        return LocationRepository()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is `RepositoryModule` your actual code? The paramters of the two functions are not used. Anyway, you could annotate your data sources with `@Inject` and `@Singleton`, and then have `XxxRepository @Inject constructor(dataSource: XxxDataSource)`. No need for any module

Comment: If I do that, I get "DataSource<java.lang.String> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method." That's with trying to inject the DataSource ```@Inject lateinit var dataSource: DataSource<T>```

Comment: I'm suggesting to use the concrete type not the generic type, e.g. `ItemDataSource`: `class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(dataSource: LocationDataSource)`.

Comment: That leads to code duplication. This means instead of having the field in the superclass, it ends up having to be in every subclass.

Comment: Well, it works if I do not inject into the base class
```open class Repository<T> constructor(var dataSource: DataSource<T>) {

    var data = this.dataSource.data
    ...
}```
Is there a way to inject the field into the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to avoid having the data source field in each repository subclass, you could add a data source type parameter and val to Repository:

```
class Repository<ValueT, DataSourceT>(val dataSource: DataSourceT) {
  ...
}

class LocationRepository: Repository<Location, LocationDataSource> @Inject constructor(dataSource: LocationDataSource): super(dataSource) {
  ...
}
```

It's better to use constructor injection than field injection, and using constructor injection, you have to pass the constructor parameters through the subclasses -- you can't do it only in the base class.